# Is it possible to use a USB Wifi dongle with STM32F429I Discovery board?

Tags: arm, wifi, stm32f4

I have been using wifi modules like ESP8266 and EMW3162, but this increases the load of work. I would like to use a usb wifi dongle (because discovery board has extra usb interface).

Is it possible? Do I need some kind of specific driver or a standard driver exists for such peripherals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usb wifi devices require their specific usb drivers to work. There is no generic driver 99% of the time. The ESP 8266 works easily because it has a serial interface, which can be bit banged of needed from most microcontrollers.